# How inelastic spin-exchange collisions works?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm studying for my bachelor thesis on Quantum Thermometry.

The core of the procedure is motion-spin mapping onto quantum states of the probe, so inserting Caesium atoms in a ultra cold Rubidium gas and letting the caesium atoms thermalise with the bath is possible to extract temperature information from the quantum states of the probes.

I can't understand formally how collisions between atoms exchange spin.